# Why use fcl::continuousCollide in FCL to report an error?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, collision-detection, fcl

I wrote a simple example of continuous collision using vs2019, but I can't always compile.
Error information：

```
C2259   'fcl::InterpMotion<S>': cannot instantiate abstract class   
C2259   'fcl::ScrewMotion<S>': cannot instantiate abstract class
```

```cpp
    auto g1 = std::make_shared<fcl::Boxf>(1, 2, 3);
    auto t1 = fcl::Transform3f::Identity();
    auto o1 = new fcl::CollisionObjectf(g1, t1);
    auto t1_final = fcl::Transform3f::Identity();
    t1_final.translation() = fcl::Vector3f(1, 0, 0);

    auto g2 = std::make_shared<fcl::Conef>(1, 3);
    auto t2 = fcl::Transform3f::Identity();
    auto o2 = new fcl::CollisionObjectf(g2, t2);
    auto t2_final = fcl::Transform3f::Identity();
    t2_final.translation() = fcl::Vector3f(-1, 0, 0);

    fcl::ContinuousCollisionRequestf request;
    fcl::ContinuousCollisionResultf result;
    std::cout << fcl::continuousCollide(o1, t1_final, o2, t2_final, request, result);

    delete o1;
    delete o2;
```

[image: 'fcl::InterpMotion': cannot instantiate abstract class]

Answer (score 0):

in
`fcl/math/motion/interp_motion.h`
`fcl/math/motion/interp_motion-inl.h`
`fcl/math/motion/screw_motion.h`
`fcl/math/motion/screw_motion-inl.h`
I had to change `double` to `S`.

```cpp
template <typename S>
bool InterpMotion<S>::integrate(double dt) const

template <typename S>
bool InterpMotion<S>::integrate(S dt) const
```